# How to sample on condition with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sampling

I hava a dataframe df like the following:

```
   Col1      Col2
0  1         T
1  1         B 
2  3         S
3  2         A
4  1         C
5  2         A
etc...
```

I would like to create two dataframes: df1 is a random sample of 10 rows such that Col2=='T'. df2 is df minus the rows in df1.

Comment: 10 rows with Col2==T are selected and put into df1. df2 if then equal to the original dataframe (df) minus the rows in df1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have a unique-indexed dataframe (and if you don't, you can simply do `.reset_index()`, apply this, and then `set_index` after the fact), you could use [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html).  [Actually, you should be able to use `sample` even if the frame *didn't* have a unique index, but you couldn't use the below method to get `df2`.]

Note that I'm using A instead of T in this example because A is the only repeated value of Col2 in the example you gave, and I'll only select 1 randomly rather than 10.

```
>>> df1 = df[df.Col2 == "A"].sample(1)
>>> df2 = df[~df.index.isin(df1.index)]
>>> df1
   Col1 Col2
3     2    A
>>> df2
   Col1 Col2
0     1    T
1     1    B
2     3    S
4     1    C
5     2    A
```